# Why php code does not echo anything?

Tags: php, svg

```
<?php
$svg_file = file_get_contents("fonts/font.svg");
$font = new DOMDocument();
$font->load($svg_file);
$glyphs = $font->getElementsByTagName('glyph');

foreach($glyphs as $g) {
    echo $g->getAttribute('glyph-name');
}
?>
```

Where am i going wrong in above code??? it does not echo anything, trying on localhost

Comment: Start with `var_dump($glyphs)`

Comment: I am absolutely new to this, can you please elaborate? thanks in advance.

Comment: Put `var_dump($glyphs)` after the `$glyphs` assignment. It will show you the contents of the variable in full detail. Any PHP tutorial should explain what `var_dump` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$font = new DOMDocument();
$font->load("fonts/font.svg");
$glyphs = $font->getElementsByTagName('glyph');

foreach($glyphs as $g) {
    echo $g->getAttribute('glyph-name');
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$font = new DOMDocument();
$font->load("fonts/font.svg");
$glyphs = $font->getElementsByTagName('glyph');
$arr_names = array();
foreach($glyphs as $g) {
    $arr_names[] = $g->nodeValue;
}
$sort($arr_names);
foreach($arr_names as $name){
    echo $name;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
$font = new DOMDocument();
$font->load("fonts/font.svg");
$glyphs = $font->getElementsByTagName('glyph');
$arr_names = array();
foreach($glyphs as $g) {
    $arr_names[] = $g->nodeValue;
}
sort($arr_names);
foreach($arr_names as $name){
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: And how do i get the value as array and echo

Comment: Try $g->nodeValue

Comment: Above got solved my requirement, it echos all the glyph names. i want to use all the glyph names as array to echo each name and count names and sort them

Comment: You need to define array before loop $arr_names = array(); and put values to array inside a loop $arr_names[] = $g->nodeValue

Comment: I am trying to but i have no clue what am i doing, i guess i need to study. Will really appreciate if you can share full code.

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much. you sorted it for me... i was trying to get data for  scss file. This helped me.